# Django get file from wrong static folder

Tags: python, django, caching

I came across another problem with django projects. I think it will be for you litte problem. Thos is working in internet project.

I run local dev server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Everything start ok but there is some reference to images to static folder, i,ve create this folder and fill with images. Project get css and js file  correct but images search in folder which doesn't exist. 
I check cache configuration and i uncommented

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
```

I found some information about clear cache in django but I do not understand too much this solution. I'm new in python, i have experience with another language. 
I will be greatful for help. thx.

=====================================

ok this is my common.py - common settings

```
<pre><code>
# Absolute filesystem path to the Django project directory:
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

# Absolute filesystem path to the top-level project folder:
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

# Site name:
SITE_NAME = basename(DJANGO_ROOT)

STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'static'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is get addres

```
"GET /media/cache/c2/d6/c2d6fe9bc49dcdb617b14a8c8f4dfaec.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 855
```

This is tree
[enter link description here](http://gsmdevices.eu/tree.html)

ok i think that i must explain somting i backup production database and import locally. I read that django can cache some information in databse but configuration should be diffrent :/.

===================================

Problem solved, DJANGO_ROOT reference to bad folder :/. This is my stupid mistake.
Sorry that i took your time for this :/.  and thx for help, you give me the clue !!

Comment: I don't see what you think this has to do with Django's cache.

Comment: i guesses :/, this is framework and it manage all of process i think, how can i find what manage this collection of images ?

Comment: Show us your STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL settings, your directory structure and the address that browser tries to get the image from.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you're trying to get an img with an url starting with `/media/`, so you need probably to configure your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings. Moreover, to serve uploaded static files in development, add this to your urls.py (assuming `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`):

```
from django.conf import settings
#...
# development media
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: Ok , it doesn't work, i had media root , but i found another things my  DJANGO_ROOT set up to /home/user :/ not do django project, do you think that is the problem and the question is why this is wrong folder :/ ?

Comment: print out the value of MEDIA_ROOT and check it is the correct one. The DJANGO_ROOT wrong setup can be certainly a problem, if it is used to create the MEDIA_URL path, as you do for the STATIC_ROOT one